# Setting up authentication Angular 2 for new router (>= rc1)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I just got authentication up and running for my angular 2 app but am now trying to upgrade to the new Router, removing the Router-deprecated. The problem is that my strategy doesn't work anymore.

In the old router, I extended the router-outlet to check if a URL was able to activate. If it wasn't, I just redirected to my login page.

In the new router however, the router-outlet doesn't exist anymore. What would be the new best strategy?

Comment: The `RouterOutlet` still exists https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b30ddfbfc5192f526ceaac525cf6965635831c46/modules/%40angular/router/src/directives/router_outlet.ts#L32

Comment: I guess this is what you're missing https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8562

Comment: Ah yes, that's what I'm missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to subscribe to the router in order to evaluate whether the user is logged in whenever the route changes, so something like this in your AppComponent:

```
constructor (private _router: Router) {} 

ngOnInit(){
  this._router.subscribe(
    next => {
      if (!userIsLoggedInOrWhatever) {
        this._router.navigate(['Login']);
      }
    }
  )    
}
```

https://angular.io/api/router/Router